# Convert Object fields to JSON

Tags: apex, rest-api, json

I have an object called `AssessmentForm` which has a lot of fields. Through an existing APEX controller I can access these specific fields by `AssessmentForm.fieldname`.

Is there a way to convert all of the fields into a JSON?

For example:

Object: `AssessmentForm`

Which has the following fields: `field1 = 5`, `field2 = 'cat'`, `field3 = 54`, `field4 = 'dog`

Would be converted to:
`{"field1": 5, "field2" : "cat", "field3" : 54, "field4": "dog"}`

For extra context, what I would like to do is send all of the form data through an API. To do so, I want to convert all of the fields in `AssessmentForm` into a JSON. The form itself has a lot of fields on it and so I'm hoping there might be a way to convert an object's fields to a JSON without having to manually code it all out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it in one line:

```
String assessmentFormString = JSON.serialize(form);
```

This assumes your form is the variable name of your apex class instance.

This `JSON` output can be directly sent to your API in the body of your request.